# Show path for more inputs Android webView

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have here the HTML and JS: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70LLLrdg/)

I want to upload more pics, that means more inputs. What can I do to show the file path and uri for each input?

```
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
    function setFilePath(file) {
       $(".lblpath").text(file);
        Android.showToast(file);
    }
    function setFileUri(uri) {
        $(".lbluri").text(uri);
        Android.showToast(uri);
    }
    function choosePhoto() {
        var file = Android.choosePhoto();
        window.alert("file = " + file);
    }
```